# che.openshift.io - Run the terminal as SUDO

Tags: eclipse-che, redhat-containers

I am using the `che.openshift.io` - Eclipse Che from Red Hat. I have a workspace of PHP Laravel Stack. When I try to run commands as SUDO from the php terminal I am getting error.

```
SUDO - not a command /
SU - must be run from a terminal
```

Can someone help me to run as root user? I have to install the `heroku CLI` from the terminal which can be done only via root user.

Answer (score 4):

In general, containers running as root is a significant security risk + containers are supposed to be immutable and installing anything inside the container is not recommended since after the restart all the packages will vanish.

Eclipse Che workspaces on `che.openshift.io` are running against Red Hat OpenShift Online clusters which do not support `sudo` and workspace containers are running using the [Arbitrary User IDs](https://docs.openshift.com/online/pro/creating_images/guidelines.html#use-uid) (This provides additional security against processes escaping the container due to a container engine vulnerability and thereby achieving escalated permissions on the host node). So, Basically you can not execute `sudo` from the workspace terminal.

> I have to install the heroku CLI from the terminal which can be done only via root user.

In order to support the Heroku CLI from the terminal you have 2 options:

- Create your own custom php image with the `Heroku CLI` installed based on the default php image used in Eclipse Che - https://github.com/eclipse/che-dockerfiles/blob/master/recipes/php/7.1/Dockerfile (and then refer to this image from the custom [devfile](https://redhat-developer.github.io/devfile/) that will feet your needs)
- Eclipse Che support vscode extensions  and you can contribute support of the [`heroku-cli`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pkosta2005.heroku-command) to the [che-plugin-registry](https://github.com/eclipse/che-plugin-registry)

Hope this helps.